# Dynamic CSS 0:N Triangles in Container

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm working on an Electron+Vue application that draws a grid styled map. For each cell (a room) I would like to indicate walls. For NSWE I can `border-left`/etc. For NW/NE/SW/SE I would like to draw an angled wall or triangle. This must be done dynamically (e.g. via classes that I inject into each cell).

There seem to be a number of ways to draw triangles and that works for a single instance or multiple if I don't need it to be dynamic. How can I do this dynamically?

Here is what I'm attempting:

```
<!-- ... inside a component -->
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr
            v-for="(row, y) in grid"
            :key="y"
        >
            <td
                v-for="(room, x) in row"
                :key="x"
                :class="roomClass(room)"
            >
                <!-- I want to conditionally add a corner triangle
                in one or more corners of this cell -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
// Component methods
roomClass(room) {
    return  {
        wallseast   : room.walls && room.walls.includes('southeast'),
        wallswest   : room.walls && room.walls.includes('southwest'),
        <!-- ...so on... -->
    };
},
```

```
<style scoped>
td.wallseast {
  /* ??? */
}

td.wallswest {
  /* ??? */
}
</style>
```

Update: A better example of what I'm doing. Below is a image showing a map with some walls. Note the top right (or NE) corner of one of the rooms. I would like to be able to draw this on any/all corners.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably wouldn't use a table... but - the concept would be the same.

You could use pseudo elements to limit the markup... and make triangles, or put an element in there... and do the border-hack trick for triangles... but I'd just use an SVG/poygon to make the triangle. You'll be just dynamically generating it, so - the extra markup is fine. It is - what it is.

You should probably have a little  view component. Then have all of the triangles in there, and based on hover or game-state - give them a class or whatever to let it know what triangle to show.

```
<room>
    <svg class='arrow ne'><polygon points='100,0 100,100 0,0'></svg>
        
    <svg class='arrow sw'><polygon points='100,100 0,100 0,0'></svg>
        

    <arrow class='sw'>
        <!-- or if you really want... you can make the shape with CSS... -->
    </arrow>
</room>
```

https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/0cdb7ccc2efd2f1f5868380d0afae436

Answer (score 0):

```
Did you mean something like this?

  


//CSS
    .sq-right {
        width: 201px;
        height: 201px;
        background-color: #fff;
        transform: rotate(30deg);
        position: absolute;
        top: -66px;
        left: -136px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .sq-left {
        width: 201px;
        height: 201px;
        background-color: #fff;
        transform: rotate(-30deg);
        position: absolute;
        top: -66px;
        left: 136px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .bg-color{
        background-color: red;
        height: 172px;
        width: 201px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 142px;
        top: 106px;
        text-align:center;
        overflow:hidden;
        
    }
    <!-- language: lang-html -->
    
        <div id="parentDiv">
          <div class="bg-color"></div>
          <div class="sq-right"></div>
          <div class="sq-left"></div>      
        </div>
    
    <!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: This resulted in only a single triangle (e.g. in one of the many "rooms"). I have updated the question with a more complete example of what I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

So in that case you have to use SVG or canvas to create multiple triangles with the help of loop.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext)
  {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(75,75);
    context.lineTo(10,75);
    context.lineTo(10,25);
    context.fill();
  }
```